# Convert dates consistently to dd/mm/yyyy format

Tags: excel, vba, date

I am attempting to convert SAP data with date format dd.mm.yyyy to Excel date format dd/mm/yyyy so I can sort it from oldest to newest.

It seems Find and Replace code is creating its own number format making any format application before and after its use pointless as it will turn any date into the American format where possible:

```
01.02.2015 -> 02/01/2015 instead of 01/02/2015  
dd.mm.yyyy -> mm/dd/yyyy instead of dd/mm/yyyy
```

Changing the format back is impossible as only some of the data is affected, as some dates do not fit this range and instead stay in a static format.

Is there either a way around this or an alternative method of finding and replacing this data? I have seen similar options here for replacing constants but none of them work for me or are ones I can use. I am unable to have a new column next to the date column as data is pasted directly from SAP.

The code I have:

```
' Change Release Date to date format
Sheets("Article List").Select
Last = LastRow(ActiveSheet)
range("K4:K" & Last).Select
Selection.Replace _
    What:=".", _
    Replacement:="/", _
    LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    MatchCase:=False, _
    SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
```

The data once formatted is copied using vlookup into my main data sheet where it should maintain the same format as this is set up with a custom format of dd/mm/yyyy.

When manually handling the data I am able to have it give the correct results using the find and replace - which uses the same code I have above as confirmed by trying to record a macro during troubleshooting.

Comment: Perhaps it's better to write a User Defined Function to do the conversion instead of replacing text. Then replace the contents of that K column to the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `LastRow()` returns Long, try this:

```
Private Function MDY2DMY(oRng As Range) As Date
    Dim oMDY As Variant, dDMY As Date
    oMDY = Split(Trim(oRng.Value), ".")
    dDMY = DateSerial(oMDY(2), oMDY(0), oMDY(1))
    MDY2DMY = dDMY
End Function

Sub ChangeMDY2DMY()
    Dim oWS As Worksheet, Last As Long, oRng As Range, dDMY As Date

    Set oWS = ActiveSheet
    Last = LastRow(oWS)
    Set oRng = oWS.Range("K4")
    Do
        If oRng.NumberFormat <> "dd/mm/yyyy" Then
            dDMY = MDY2DMY(oRng) ' Get the date value from M.D.Y. format
            oRng.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy" ' Change the number format
            oRng.Value = dDMY ' Change the value
        End If
        Set oRng = oRng.Offset(1) ' Move down 1 row
    Loop Until oRng.Row > Last
    Set oRng = Nothing
    Set oWS = Nothing
End Sub
```

Code has been added to prevent another run on the cells.

Comment: Many thanks, using this though I realised I didn't need to convert between the two like that as I could break my original value down. Put me on the right track though and believe i've solved it now.

Answer (score 0):

I have spent around two hours searching all over google for an answer to this, and the only VBA function which I've gotten to convert a date into a forward slash dd/mm/yyyy format, is the TextToColumns function.

```
Sub CleanDate()
Dim LastRow As Long

Sheets("Article List").Select
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, 
LookIn:=xlValues, _
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
Range("K4", Cells(LastRow, "K")).Select

Range("K4:K" & LastRow).TextToColumns Destination:=Range("K4"), 
DataType:=xlDelimited, _
FieldInfo:=Array(1, xlDMYFormat)

End Sub
```

I got the idea from this page - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e3522eac-13b1-476c-8766-d70794131cc8/strange-date-conversion-while-using-vba-replace-function?forum=isvvba

Answer (score 0):

Effectively the line:

```
 Selection.Replace _
 What: = ".", _
 Replacement: = "/",
 ....
```

performs the wrong change operation. It only works if the day of the origin date is greater than 12. In that case the code performs the ***Replace*** perfectly.

To avoid that the solution is to format the cells in text mode and do a ***For Each*** with a ***Replace***.

This code works perfectly.

```
Private Sub f_MyFunction()
    'Obligatory so that it does not travel the entire column
    Range("K4", "K" & Range("K4").End(xlDown).Row).Select

   'Obligatory so that Excel does not swap ddmm-> mmdd
    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"

    'This method does not generate swap errors
    For Each obj_cell In Selection.Cells
        With obj_cell
            If IsNull(obj_cell) Then Exit Sub
            obj_cell.Value = Replace(.Text, ".", "/")
        End With
    Next
    'And now change the format to DATE
    Selection.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy;@"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have continued to investigate and I have found another method that makes the change immediately, although it leaves it in the format **dd/mm/yyyy**. If you want to change '/' to '-' you must use the ***For Each*** method with a ***Replace*** mentioned in my previous answer.

This other method uses *Range.TextToColumns* and *FieldInfo parameter: = Array (0, xlDMYFormat)*

**It's amazing but it's just one line. In addition, the cell is not only formatted on date but also admits any character as a date separator.**

```
'From K4 to last row
Range("K4", "K" & Range("K4").End(xlDown).Row).TextToColumns FieldInfo:=Array(0, xlDMYFormat)
'1.2.2019 -> 01/02/2019
'1_2_2019 -> 01/02/2019
'1*2*2019 -> 01/02/2019...

'To do it over only one cell
Range("A1").TextToColumns FieldInfo:=Array(0, xlDMYFormat)
```